# Understanding multi-core SMP systems

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, multicore

I'm trying to understand how does **multi-core** systems work and how to program efficient programs for systems with **many cores**. I know this is very hard topic but i'm very interested in fastest solutions possible.

First of all, i'm trying to understand how does threading work. It's obvious, that in most cases multithreading can increase the performance dramatically. According to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computing%29) page, this is how multithreading work:

[image]

But why is switching between **N** threads is faster than just running **N** threads one by one ? How can threading work on system with only one CPU ?

Next, what is the **point or multi-core programming**? I assume that the point is to split threads between cores and split tasks between them ? But how can i split 8 threads on 4 CPU's system equally ?

Do i have to use [processor affinity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_affinity) (**cpu_affinity**) to split **threads/processes** between CPU's ? Can i create 4 threads using **pthread_create** on system with 4 CPU's to run each thread on each CPU ?

How [hyper-threading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading) helps and is it helps at all ? How can we use **CPU cache** programming for multi-core systems ?

Why is this so hard for big old projects, like MySQL for example, to fully use advantages of many-CPU systems ?

I'm interested in theory of this problem and also in practical solutions/examples/projects/books/articles for **Linux** systems (using C).

I know this is increasingly important topic and I hopes I'm not only one interested.

Comment: Multiple threads of execution (roughly) just have an instruction pointer (and more generally a register set+stack) of their own. Having multiple processors means you can have more than one of these active simultaneously. Having hyperthreading means that even though (approximately) only one is making progress at the same time a) the chunks of progress can be *much* smaller and b) the cost of swapping between (typically) two threads becomes much cheaper. Thread affinity may/may not help. Your OS will need a chunk of CPU time and if the threads aren't evenly balanced it may make performance worse

Comment: I'm sorry, but we'd need to quote an entire book or even several books to answer all of your questions. Please try to split this into several smaller questions, otherwise the answers would be too large and thus less meaningful.

Comment: can you please suggest any books on any of this topics ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference between switching N threads and running N threads one by one is what happens when a thread, temporarily, can make no further forward progress. If you switch N threads and one of those threads temporarily can't make forward progress, say it's waiting for data to be read from the disk, another thread can make forward progress. If you ran them completely sequentially, then the CPU would be wasted while a thread was waiting for disk I/O to complete.

Hyper-threading helps by allowing you to make fuller use of CPU core execution resources. For example, if a thread isn't doing any floating point math, the floating point units of that core are wasted. With hyper-threading, another thread can use those execution units.

On a typical modern core, operations take many clock cycles and a number of operations are in progress at a time. This means a core typically has many extra execution resources that it can't use at any particular instant. Hyper-threading allows a higher percentage of those execution resources (barrel shifters, adders, logic units, branch units, and so on) to be used. Typically, hyper-threading may improve performance by 10% to 15%. The benefit isn't greater because the threads also steal execution resources from each other, pollute each others use of cache, and so on.

The CPU cache is used automatically and you generally don't have to do anything special to use it. Perhaps the most common exception is dealing with false sharing or cache ping-ponging.

Comment: Even in the case where there's two threads fighting for the FPU hyperthreading still gives you an extra register set that can be used to reduce the cost of context switches.